# Concurrent Queue class in java with aggregate functions

Tags: java, c#

What's the equivalent of ConcurrentQueue class in C# in Java. The ConcurrentQueue class provides aggregate functions which can be applied to elements in the queue.

```
Ex: private ConcurrentQueue<Double> CPU = new ConcurrentQueue<Double>();
.......
double average = CPU.Average();
```

Is there a similar concurrent queue class in java which provides aggregate functions.

Thanks

Comment: java doesn't have real generics. Whatever the collection type it's not going to support `double`. You will probably need a bunch of horrible hacks related to working around java's generics bad design.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `ConcurrentQueue` provides no such functions. It implements `IEnumerable` which in turn has extension methods defined that you call.